# coloring jquery modal

Tags: jquery, html

I've a standard code for jquery modal (with grey color).
How make a colorful toolbox from Grey to example blue? 
And this script can use for many dialog... for example #dialog1=blue and #dialog2=green
This's my standard code.

```
<script>
// increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });

    $( "#opener1" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuerys theme builder ( http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ )

You can design your entire color scheme, and then save the css from the site and it will color all of jQuery ui, not just the dialog.

Cheers.

-- UPDATE --

Once you design what you want your dialog to look like, open the css file and copy the following lines:

You will need to create custom class names for each one, and then remove the default class from the dialog when you create it, and then add the new class to it instead.

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { position: relative; border: 0; padding: .5em 1em; background: none; overflow: auto; zoom: 1; }
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane { text-align: left; border-width: 1px 0 0 0; background-image: none; margin: .5em 0 0 0; padding: .3em 1em .5em .4em; }
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants two dialogues to be in two different colors >.<

Comment: I've download full jquery (include theme) before in default version. In my quetion. How to make a different theme or color box. for example the box dialog1=yellow or sunny theme and dialog2=grey or default theme
thank you